# Как отсортировать и вывести значение из масива обьектов в js?

Tags: javascript

Нужно вытянуть все total из массива объектов в зависимости от флага true или false и суммировать все total исходя из этого флага.

```
const totals = [
    {
      total: 757565,
      income: true,
    },
    {
      total: 33,
      income: false,
    },
    {
      total: 75,
      income: true,
    },
    {
      total: 757565,
      income: true,
    },
  ];
```

Comment: Как связан заголовок вопроса и то, что написано в теле?

Comment: totals.filter(el => el.income).map(el => sum += el.total) ?

Comment: @Ceri, reduce..

Answer (score 2):

```js
const totals = [{
    total: 757565,
    income: true,
  },
  {
    total: 33,
    income: false,
  },
  {
    total: 75,
    income: true,
  },
  {
    total: 757565,
    income: true,
  },
];

const INCOME = false;
console.log(totals.reduce((a, c) => a + (c.income === INCOME && c.total), 0));
```

Comment: @gregzakharov, почему? А что если вместо булеана там будет другой тип данных?

Comment: @gregzakharov, я хочу к примеру найти все обьекты, где income больше 10, и все... надо ходить, искать, менять функцию снова. А так все сразу готово. На самом деле это мелочь, но я бы оставил так.

Answer (score 0):

```
const getSumByFlag = totals => {
  let trueSum;
  let falseSum;
  for (i=0; i<totals.length; i++) {
    const flag = totals[i].income;
    const total = totals[i].total;
    flag === true ? trueSum += total : falseSum += total;
  }
  let result = {
    incomeTrueSum: trueSum,
    incomeFalseSum: falseSum
  };
  return result;
};
```